# Modelling when composition needs access to enclosing class?

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

I'm having questions for the following design for a `Canvas`, where certain `domain` objects should be represented by different `figures`:

I need an "enclosing" class that serves as the domain object. It holds the data that should be getting presented to the user, eg `State`.
This State has a name, of course a state, etc as variables.

This State should be represented visually by a `Rectangle`. Thus I thought using `Composition Pattern`:

```
interface Drawable {
 void draw();
}

class Rectangle implements Drawable {
    @Override
    void draw() {
        //draw the state as a rectangle depending on the state variables, draw the name etc.
    }
}

interface Figure {
    Drawable getDrawable();
}

class State implements Figure {
    boolean state;
    Rectangle rectangle;
    public Drawable getDrawable() { return rectangle; }
}
```

Now I probably also have other objects, which also implements `Figure` and thereby provide a specific `Drawable` for painting them.

My problem here is: the following would execute the right `draw()` method for every object, BUT the draw method would need all the information of it's enclosing class.

```
List<Figure> list;
for (Figure obj : list) {
    obj.getDrawable().draw();
}
```

How can the `draw()` method know about eg the `State` and the name-variable of it's enclosing `State` object, as it should base it's drawing on it?

The only thing I came up with is:

```
interface Drawable {
 void draw(Figure figure);
}

for (Drawable obj : list) {
    obj.getDrawable().draw(obj);
}
```

But it does not feel right to call an object, and in the same statement supply this object as a paramter!

How could this be done better?

Comment: For this loop `for (Drawable obj : list) {
    obj.getDrawable().draw(obj);
}` how will `obj.getDrawable()` compile ? `obj` is of type `Drawable`. `Drawable` doesnot have `getDrawable()`

Comment: Don't you mean `List<Figure>` instead of `List<Drawable>`?

Comment: @sp00m I think he/she does mean it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the domain object selects the Drawable implementation that is used to represent it, you already have a logical place where you can supply the reference to the Drawable:

```
 public class AStateObject {

      public Drawable getDrawable() {
           return new Rectangle(this);
      }

 }
```

So each drawable knows the state object it is supposed to draw. This excludes the use of a single instance per Drawable subclass, but Drawables should be cheap to create in this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You could pass the attributes you'll need to draw when you're instantiating the drawable. For example, using an abstract class instead of an interface:

```
public abstract class Drawable {

    private final Map<String, Object> attributes;

    public Drawable(final Map<String, Object> attributes) {
        this.attributes = attributes;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public <T> T getAttribute(final String key) {
        return (T) attributes.get(key);
    }

    public abstract void draw();

}

public class Rectangle extends Drawable {

    public Rectangle(final Map<String, Object> attributes) {
        super(attributes);
    }

    @Override
    public void draw() {
        final String name = getAttribute("name");
        System.out.println(name);
    }

}

public interface Figure {

    public Drawable getDrawable();

}

public class State implements Figure {

    private final Rectangle rectangle;

    public State() {
        final Map<String, Object> attributes = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        attributes.put("name", "the rectangle");
        rectangle = new Rectangle(attributes);
    }

    @Override
    public Drawable getDrawable() {
        return rectangle;
    }

}
```

Then, when calling:

```
final List<Figure> figures = new ArrayList<Figure>();
figures.add(new State());
for (final Figure figure : figures) {
    figure.getDrawable().draw(); // prints "the rectangle"
}
```

Comment: that's a neat approach, though in my case that would add a big overhead to my implementation.